# When posting to an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app, "[FromBody]MyClass data" is often null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I encountered this interesting (frustrating) problem recently after upgrading from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1. Previously I would POST data to the web app, with the receiving method looking something like this:

```
public IActionResult OnPostAddNewDataAsync([FromBody]MyClass data)
{
    //...
}
```

where `MyClass` might be something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
    public integer Value1 {get; set;}
}
```

(For reference, to hit the endpoint from Javascript, you can do it like this:

```
 await PostDataAsync("AddNewData", {
      "Field1": "Hello I am",
      "Value1": 7
 });

async function PostDataAsync(handler, data)
{
    return await $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname + "?handler=" + handler,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers:
        {
            RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}
```

it took me a while to figure that out!).

This worked fine.

After updating .NET Core 3.1, many of my POST methods stopped working, and the `[FromBody]` value would be null.

Note: As part of my upgrade to .NET Core 3.1 I removed references to `Newtonsoft.Json`, deciding instead to try and use the new `System.Text.Json`. This would turn out to be important!

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned, references to `Newtonsoft.Json` were removed, leaving any automatic Json conversion to be dealt with by `System.Text.Json`. It turns out that this was the cause of the problem as `System.Text.Json` is not as flexible (Microsoft themselves say so, and that it is intended to be so: [How to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to).

Before .NET Core 3, ASP.NET Core used `Newtonsoft.Json` internally, and now it uses `System.Text.Json` instead.

An example is with a numeric field, e.g `MyClass.Value1`. If from Javascript you pass "10" or 10, `Newtonsoft.Json` will cope with that and recognise both as 10. With `System.Text.Json` by default that field cannot have surrounding quotes, and if in the Json you posted it did you'd be getting a null `[FromBody]` value.

The quickest solution to this problem is to revert to `Newtonsoft.Json` for these cases, and that is easily done by:

- installing the Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`
- in Startup.cs, update the following method as so:

.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    //All your other code:
    //...
}
```

This is taken directly from [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/).

Having made this change everything worked as expected again.

I am aware that `System.Text.Json` can be configured with custom parsers to handle these kind of situations (which I do use elsewhere), but I have dozens of POST methods and rather than updating all of them to work with the new way, it was a lot easier to do as described above.

Comment: System.Text.Json is not ready for prime time yet, stick to good old Newtonsoft Json.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was really struggling with the same issue.

Comment: but where is no method AddNewtonsoftJson in .NET 6.